# Renaming Fields in R using a loop

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame that has about 25 columns and I want to rename the fields names for each column to a set name will the column number. For example column 4 will be called Col4, column 5 will be called Col5..etc.

I could write my R code so that:

```
      colnames(df)[1]<-'Col1'
      colnames(df)[2]<-'Col2'
      ... x25
```

However there must be a better way. I have decided to use a loop instead where my code is:

```
      for (i in 1:ncol(df))
       {
       colnames(df)[i]<-'Col'&i
        }
```

But I get the error:

'Error in "Col" & i : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types'

How can I correct the code in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use functions `paste` or `paste0` when handling characters.

In your case, this should do the trick.

```
colnames(df) <- paste0("Col", seq(1,25))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 df <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=25,nrow=1)) # create a dataframe with this shape
 labels <- paste0("Col",seq(1,25,1))
 colnames(df) <- labels
```

And then it will look like this:

```
> df 
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Col10 Col11 Col12 Col13 Col14 
Col15 Col16 Col17 Col18 Col19 Col20
1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
Col21 Col22 Col23 Col24 Col25
1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```